# iTerm2 hide marks

Tags: iterm2, terminal-emulator

I recently install the Shell Integration for iTerm2, but it also added those little arrows (called marks) when entering as shell command, which are really annoying.

Is there any way to disable/hide them, I cannot find online?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-preferences.html) you can disable this from Profiles -> Open Profiles -> Edit Profiles -> Select your profile -> Terminal -> Uncheck "Show mark indicators"

[image: Disabling mark indicators in iTerm2]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [dynamic profiles](https://iterm2.com/documentation-dynamic-profiles.html), the option is `Show Mark Indicators`, i.e you would include the following in the json file for the profile to disable showing marks:

> "Show Mark Indicators" : false